# Custom Argument Resolver for ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to use a custom argument inside a method annotated with the ExceptionHandler in spring mvc 3.2 to handle an exception.
However I still get this exception when the method is executed:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable resolver for argument[1] [type=com.example.domain.CustomArgument]

The Controller method looks like:

```
@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
@ResponseBody
public Error handleIOException(IOException ex, CustomArgument customArgument) {
    return new Error(customArgument.getMessage());
}
```

And I'm using the following xml config:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="com.example.spring.CustomArgumentWebArgumentResolver" scope="singleton">
            <constructor-arg ref="customArgumentService" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="customArgumentService" class="com.example.service.CustomArgumentService" scope="singleton" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver" scope="singleton">
    <property name="customArgumentResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.example.service.CustomArgumentService" scope="singleton">
                <constructor-arg ref="customArgumentService" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" scope="singleton">
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="forward:/error" />
</bean>
```

And I believe mvc:annotation-driven is already assigning a ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver, so how can I add the customArgumentResolver to that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For several ExceptionResolvers try using HandlerExceptionResolverComposite. Something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite">
    <property name="exceptionResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver">
                <constructor-arg ref="exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
                <constructor-arg ref="simpleMappingExceptionResolver" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```